# any recommendation for using css3 with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

mainly i want to use css3 gradients , round border and text shadows and transitions with jquery in such a way that my code will become cross browser compliant and i need not to worry about browsers while using css3.
what is the best practice for using css3 with jquery?
do you have any recommendation?
do you have any link to plugin or something through which i can utilize power of css3 in older brwosers too?
if yes, then please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, you can't use css3 with non-compliant browser... So you'll have css3 for modern browsers and worry about others with js(jquery)/css. I don't think one approach will compliment another, they'll be two separate things one working for one set of browsers, the other for another.

It depends on the project of course, but consider just using css3 and have some visual degradation in older browsers.

If that's not acceptable, and if you'll go out of the way and will be maintaining the css/js for older browsers, that will also work for modern (if done correctly of course). Then why bother with css3?